# Is there data on the frequency of occurrence of the greengrocer's apostrophe?

Tags: punctuation

I've heard words such as 'ubiquitous' used to describe how prolific the presence of the greengrocer's apostrophe is, but is there any actual data available on how prolific it is in everyday life ( signs, advertising etc.?)

Comment: You can check here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greengrocer%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreengrocer%20%27s%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm not sure that helps to figure out the frequency with which shops mistakenly put apostrophes in promotional materials like signs, Josh. :P

Comment: @JohnClifford - it is probably the only available source  of its usage frequency in writing. As for road signs I guess you have to take a walk :)

Comment: It would be a great source if OP were just looking for how often in writing people say the word "greengrocer's" but that's just the name of the kind of apostrophe under discussion. :)

Comment: Does that mean the erroneous apostrophe in plural words? I'm not familiar with the phrase.